# Solr : combine a min() facet with a range facet with nested document

Tags: solr, nested, facet

Actual Solr version : 8.2

I have a "complex" solr schema with nested document and I have some problems to query. Specially when I have to build some facet.

Here an simplified version of my solr schema with some datas :

```
{
    "id": "VFF_A",
    "name": "Jean slim blue",
    "type": "REFCO",
    "skus": [{
            "id": "VFF_A_123",
            "type": "SKU",
            "price": 6.0
        }, {
            "id": "VFF_A_234",
            "type": "SKU",
            "price": 4.0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "VFF_B",
    "name": "Jean slim red",
    "type": "REFCO",
    "skus": [{
            "id": "VFF_B_123",
            "type": "SKU",
            "price": 12.0
        }, {
            "id": "VFF_B_234",
            "type": "SKU",
            "price": 12.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to query on all document of type REFCO and get for each the min(price) of their children (SKU). Then, I want to build a range facet of these min prices.

To be more clear, following the previous example, I search to get this result :

- First sku min price => 4.0
- Second sku min price => 12.0
- Range facet result =>

```
"facets": {
    "count": 3,
    "price": {
        "buckets": [{
                "val": 0.0,
                "count": 1
            }, {
                "val": 5.0,
                "count": 0
            }, {
                "val": 10.0,
                "count": 1
            }, {
                "val": 15.0,
                "count": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Actually I can build a range price with following json.facet param

```
{ 
    "price" : {
        "type": "range",
        "field": "price",
        "start": "0",
        "end": "15",
        "gap": "5",
        "domain": { 
            "blockChildren" : "type:REFCO",
        }
    }
}
```

But it take the four sku price, and I need to get the min(price) of each REFCO.

Is it possible to do this ?

Thank lots for your help

Comment: Could you use [nested faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html#Nestedfacetexample)? I have no experience with child documents, but as long as you can create the min facet, you can add another `facet` element as the child of that facet, which then operates on the values generated by the previous facet step. That way you should be able to add a range facet below the one extracting the minimum value for the set (first the min facet, then the range facet as nested facet under that).

Comment: It's a lead, but I experienced a problem to get the min price of skus. And from the doc, I just see we can't change the domain on stat func (like min max ..) : `Users can also override the "domain" of a facet that partitions data, using an explicit domain attribute whose value is a JSON object that can support various options for restricting, expanding, or completely changing the original domain before the buckets are computed for the associated facet.`